# Which code style is better in terms of readability and performance?

Tags: c, performance, error-handling, conditional-statements, readability

I am wondering which code style is better for

1. human readability
2. program performance

Let's imagine we have 2 functions:

```
// first one
void foo(void) {
    if (error)
        exit(1);
    ....
}

// second one
void bar(void) {
    if (!error) {
        ....
    }
    else
        exit(1);
}
```

Both of them work in the same way in terms of execution, but which code style is preferable?

Comment: The both examples use a bad code style.:)

Comment: Readability is probably a matter of opinion. As for performance, I'd be surprised if there's any difference at all.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, could you provide a code snippet with a good code style? :)

Comment: @Laughing_Man It is enough to see the code that I provided in my answers. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63635543/c-printing-from-char-array-produces-erroneous-characters/63637317#63637317

Comment: It's bad code style to completely exit an application deep inside some function if some exceptional situation arises in that function. That's what exceptions were invented for (but probably not available in your C context), or (older concept) special return values like -1 or NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to choose out of these two only, I'd choose the first one.

Reason:

1. It's simple. (does not use any operator like !)
2. It does not need comments to explain what happens inside.
   (self-readable code)
3. It avoids extra pair of { } which makes the code more readable
4. Both performs nearly the same, I highly doubt there will be a
   difference in performance.

Hence, first one is preferable.